# Javascript Match and RegExp Issue -- Strange Behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have been trying to use a simple jQuery operation to dynamically match and store all anchor tags and their texts on the page. But I have found a weird behavior. When you are using match() or exec(), if you designate the needle as a separate RegExp object or a pattern variable, then your query matches only one instance among dozens in the haystack.

And if you designate the pattern like this

```
match(/needle/gi)
```

then it matches every instance of the needle.

Here is my code.

You can even fire up Firebug and try this code right here on this page.

```
var a = {'text':'','parent':[]}; 

$("a").each(function(i,n) {

    var module = $.trim($(n).text());
    a.text += module.toLowerCase() + ',' + i + ','; 

    a.parent.push($(n).parent().parent()); 

});

var stringLowerCase = 'b';

var regex = new RegExp(stringLowerCase, "gi");
//console.log(a.text);
console.log("regex 1: ", regex.exec(a.text));

var regex2 = "/" + stringLowerCase + "/";
console.log("regex 2: ", a.text.match(regex2));

console.log("regex 3: ", a.text.match(/b/gi));
```

For me it is returning:

```
regex 1:  ["b"]
regex 2: null
regex 3: ["b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b"]
```

Can anyone explain the root of this behavior?

**EDIT**: I forgot to mention that for regex1, it doesn't make any difference whether you add the flags "gi" for global and case insensitive matching. It still returns only one match.

**EDIT2**: SOlved my own problem. I still don't know why one regex1 matches only one instance, but I managed to match all instances using the match() and the regex1.

So..this matches all and dynamically!

```
var regex = new RegExp(stringLowerCase, "gi");
console.log("regex 2: ", a.text.match(regex));
```

Comment: What is the content of a.text

Comment: a is just an object with two elements. I defined it at the top of the code. Its context is probably the document object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not unusual behaviour at all. In regex 1 you are only checking for 1 instance of it where in regex 3 you have told it to return all instances of the item by using the /gi argument.

In Regex 2  you are assuming that "/b/" === /b/ when it doesn't. "/b/" !== /b/. "/b/" is a string that is searching so if you string has "/b/" in it then it will return  while /b/ means that it needs to search between the slashes so you could have "abc" and it will return "b"

I hope that helps.

**EDIT:**

Looking into it a little bit more, the `exec` methods returns the first match that it finds rather than all the matches that it finds.

**EDIT:**

```
var myRe = /ab*/g;
var str = "abbcdefabh";
var myArray;
while ((myArray = myRe.exec(str)) != null)
{
  var msg = "Found " + myArray[0] + ".  ";
  msg += "Next match starts at " + myRe.lastIndex;
  console.log(msg);
}
```

Having a look at it again it definitely does return the first instance that it finds. If you looped through it then would return more.

Why it does this? I have no idea...my JavaScript Kung Fu clearly isnt strong enough to answer that part

Comment: I should have made it clear. For the regx1, it doesn't make a difference when I added "gi" to the definition of the RegExp object. Try it yourself.

Comment: Do you know why it does that? I did add the g flag in the RegExp definition, so it should do a global match, right?

Answer (score 2):

The reason regex 2 is returning null is that you're passing "/b/" as the pattern parameter, while "b" is actually the only thing that is actually part of the pattern. The slashes are shorthand for regex, just as [ ] is for array. So if you were to replace that to just new regex("b"), you'd get one match, but only one, since you're omitting the "global+ignorecase" flags in that example. To get the same results for #2 and #3, modify accordingly:

```
var regex2 = stringLowerCase;
console.log("regex 2: ", a.text.match(regex2, "gi"));
console.log("regex 3: ", a.text.match(/b/gi));
```

Answer (score 0):

regex2 is a string, not a RegExp, I had trouble too using this kind of syntax, tho i'm not really sure of the behavior.

Edit : Remebered : for regex2, JS looks for "/b/" as a needle, not "b".

Comment: But what about regex1? That should have worked. How did you end up solving your trouble?